# Vscode editor emmet for html not working in twig files. How to enable this feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing html snippets in twig file and emmet for html does no action. i'm just having suggestions. and when i hit tab it not creating element

How to enable this feature?

Answer (score 17):

Go setting search emmet, go include languages, press add item fill form with `item:twig`, `value:html`.

or use json settings:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "twig": "html"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution myself:
Vscode settings emmet include languages
here add the key and value : for key is TWIG or any language you perform and value is HTML.
Voilà !!! everything works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).